# Can we make a set out of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ pairs, given limit?

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, epsilon-delta

If I was given that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$, for some $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

This means that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$, such that $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

These $\delta$ values for corresponding $\epsilon$ exist, but are unknown.

Given this can I make a set like:
$$S=\{(\epsilon,\delta)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\mid (\epsilon>0)\wedge(\delta>0:(\forall x:|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon))\}$$
(I didn't know how to write it in a way for everyone to understand).
Essentially I want to make a set (or show it exists) of all possible $\epsilon$-$\delta$ pairs satisfying the limit definition. Is the set possible? Why / why not?

---

I can think of the Zorn's lemma, as this seems like a 'maximal set', but I don't know how to apply it. What kind of ordering would it be? What are the chains?

Maybe I can make a family: $F=\{U_i\mid i\in\mathbb R\}:U_i=\{\delta\mid\forall x: |x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<i\}$ ?

I've only ever seen Zorn's lemma in a proof showing every vector space has a basis.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set so you can use the axiom schema of specification on it

Comment: This set is perfectly valid. It might be worth noting that if $(\varepsilon_0,\delta_0)\in S$, then $(\varepsilon_0,\delta_1)\in S$ for any $\delta_1$ satisfying $0<\delta_1<\delta_0$. So if the limit exists, then the graph of $S$ in the $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ plane is a collection of vertical line segments. (On the other hand, $S$ is *not* a function.)

Comment: @Joe thanks for confirming that for me, it's one of the reasons I initially asked this question. If I want to make a function out of $S$, is that possible? (Should I be posting it as a separate question?)

Comment: @DavidLui I've only read the statement of the axiom, but it is probably the answer I am looking for. Please make the comment into an answer if possible.

Comment: You could define the function$$C=\{(\varepsilon,\delta)\in\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}\mid\varepsilon>0\text{ and }\delta=\max\{\delta'>0\mid0<|x-x_0|<\delta'\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\}\} \, .$$
If $\varepsilon>0$, then $C(\varepsilon)$ returns the maximum $\delta$ that satisfies the implication $0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$. However, even if the limit exists, it is not guaranteed that there is  maximum $\delta$ which satisfies the aforementioned implication.

Comment: So it is not clear how useful this function is. To be honest, it is not clear how useful the set that you have defined is, but it is good that you are thinking about these things.

Comment: @Joe ur comments have really helped. Wish I could award u some reputation or something.

Comment: @KraZZ: I'm glad I could help. Don't worry that you can't award me any reputation—a thank-you is much more valuable.

Answer (score 5):

One small correction in your definition of limit: the implication should be $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Yes, your set $S$ is fine.  You don't need to do anything more to prove that it exists--you have defined it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, that was careless of me. As for the set $S$, I was actually looking for a reason why such a set is valid or not. If that makes sense...